# query parameters and express SSR

Tags: reactjs, express

I have an existing ReactJS app which uses the querystring npm to read query params.

I use the following code:

```
const queryString = require('query-string')

const query = queryString.parse(location.search)
```

At the moment, I am trying to convert to an SSR app, but whenever I build the solution, it compiles but running the server (expressjs) results in the following error message:

```
var query = queryString.parse(location.search);
                              ^
ReferenceError: location is not defined
```

Any idea how to fix this? Do I still need to use the querystring npm, or solve this in expressJS?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error says that `location` variable is `undefined`, because `location` is browser property and on node you can't access `location` since basically there is no `location` on server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location` only exists on browsers.

If you want to parse the qs on the server you need to parse it directly from the request:

```
var query = queryString.parse(req.query);
```

Or if you want the logic to run client-side only you could use:

```
var query = (typeof document === 'undefined') ? {} : queryString.parse(location.search);
```

Comment: thnx, but if I use your first solution, and run my dev machine locally using npm start, I get the following error: ./src/components/Results/ResultsPage.js
  Line 22:  'req' is not defined  no-undef Does that mean that I can only continue developing with my server side server up and running? edit: even trying to run my node server results in var query = queryString.parse(req.query);
                              ^

ReferenceError: req is not defined

Comment: you need to use the request object from your express API endpoint, [basic example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)